# Calculate total of each added row separately and total of all rows in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript and facing a problem. I have invoice rows which can be added by pressing on a button. Now i want to calculate the total amount for each row separately(for which the formula is (quantity * price). And the total of all rows combined should become the total of the invoice. The problem is that when I enter the price and quantity in first row, it calculates the total but when I add a new row, it does not calculate the total for new added row after entering the value. Kindly help me in this regard.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("price").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  if (x != "") {
    document.getElementById("total").value = x * y;
  }
}

function add_fields() {

  var tableid = document.getElementById('product_table');
  var row = document.createElement("tr");

  row.innerHTML =
    '<td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" oninput="myFunction()">  </td>' +
  '<td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" oninput = "myFunction()" > < /td>' +
  '<td><input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly></td>';

  tableid.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="product_table">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" oninput="myFunction();"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" oninput="myFunction();"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Row" onclick="add_fields();">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation instead - add a *single* listener to the container, listen for `input` events. Then, from the `target` property of the event, you can get the changed `input` element. Use `.closest` to get to the parent `<tr>`, and then from its descendants, you can get to the associated `price`, `quantity`, and `total` `<input>`s, and assign values appropriately.

Note that this adds the handler using Javascript, rather than with inline HTML attributes, which are generally considered to be pretty poor practice and can be difficult to manage. Also, duplicate IDs in a single document is *invalid HTML* - IDs aren't needed anyway here, because the `input`s you want are always in a predictable order inside each `<tr>`. So, you can remove the `id` and the `onclick` attributes from the HTML and from the `row.innerHTML` string:

```js
const table = document.getElementById('product_table');
table.addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
  const tr = target.closest('tr');
  const [price, quantity, total] = tr.querySelectorAll('input');
  total.value = price.value * quantity.value;
});
function add_fields() {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML =
    '<td><input type="text" name="price">  </td > ' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="quantity"> </td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="total" readonly></td>';
  table.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="product_table">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="price"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total" readonly></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Row" onclick="add_fields();">
```